# Reference for the Dunford-Pettis Theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Does anyone have a book reference for the Dunford-Pettis theorem as stated in the Wikipedia article  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability.

Comment: See page 285 of Bogachev's *Measure Theory: volume 1*. It's stated using analytic rather than probabilistic notation, but the mathematics is the same.

Comment: Brilliant thanks :)